# Python 3.11 Using FastAPI: "cannot import name 'NotRequired' from 'typing' (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/typing.py)"

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, typing, uvicorn

I was working on a FastAPI application and suddenly my Docker container was not able to run the server anymore. When I run the code locally outside of a container, it works fine.

When I run it in the Docker container, I get this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 5, in <module>
    from uvicorn.main import main
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uvicorn.config import Config
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 26, in <module>
    from uvicorn._types import ASGIApplication
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/_types.py", line 52, in <module>
    from typing import NotRequired
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: cannot import name 'NotRequired' from 'typing' (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/typing.py)
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.0a1-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000" ]
```

Here is the command I use to run the image:

```bash
docker run --name service-name -d -it -p 5000:5000 mycompany/service-name
```

I also tried pulling the image to a new server and it didn't work, which is kind of what I expected.

Any idea what could be wrong? The only thing that is different is I am running a virtual environment on my local machine outside of the container.

Comment: Try a newer image version, for example `3.11.5-alpine3.18`

Comment: It's so weird, I am using Pyhon 3.11.0 on my local machine where it works, but your suggestion worked. Thank you!

Comment: Notice the "a1" in "python:3.11.0a1-alpine", i.e. the very first alpha build there was of Python 3.11, so I'm not surprised it was incomplete.

Comment: If you wonder about the explanation, `3.11.0` on your machine is newer than `3.11.0a1` - the latter is the first alpha release, that came approx. a year before first "normal" release. You can change version specifier in the address bar [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3110a1/) to see what changes were introduced. PEP664(`NotRequired`) is mentioned in `3.11.0b1` first (first beta) - apparently it was added to one of alpha releases, but not mentioned there. After beta, there are release candidates (`rc`) and only then - "normal" release without fourth version component.

Comment: (Sorry, it should read [PEP 655](https://peps.python.org/pep-0655/), I failed to remember the number correctly)

Comment: Gotcha, makes more sense now. Thanks guys.